# JavaScript escape quotes when selecting element by attribute value

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a variable that can contain both single quotes and double.

Using this variable, I want to select an element whose attribute value is equal to that variable. I do this with a CSS attribute selector like so:

```js
const cat = "Children's/Kids";
const div = document.querySelector(`[category='${cat}']`);
```

```html
<div category="Children's/Kids"></div>
```

Currently, if the variable contains single quotes or double quotes, it doesn't work, as `cat` is wrapped in single quotes in the selector, and if `cat` contains a single quote, the final selector result will have an unclosed quote.

For example, the selector in the above example will be `[category='Children's/Kids']`, which will produce a `DOMException` since it is an invalid selector.

If it doesn't contain quotes, it works.

Solutions?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can let [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) handle the quote escaping for you:

```js
const cat = "Children's/Kids";
const div = document.querySelector(`[category=${JSON.stringify(cat)}]`);

console.log('Selector:', `[category=${JSON.stringify(cat)}]`)
console.log('Element:', div)
```

```html
<div category="Children's/Kids"></div>
```